# SQL: Order by date, only month and year given - Full Group on

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sql-order-by

I have an SQL database which is setted to full group on mode. My goal is to get the amount of rows (ID's) for every month. This is why I say `Group By Datum`. Because of the full group mode I cannot simply say `Order By created_at`. Because I have selected only `%m.%Y`. So I can only work with `Datum` which is cointaing my month and year.

I already tried to connect those values like `CONCAT('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m'), "-01 00:00:00")` but also this isn't working... Even if I turn it into a UNIX Timestamp it isn't working: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m'), "-01 00:00:00"))`

I even tried this one:
`Order By Year(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y')), Month DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m')` But it isn't also working...

How can I sort my result by month and year without changing the `Select` values?
Sofar this is my actual SQL Query. Not working either.. I am nearly trying to find a solution since 1 hour...

`SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m.%Y') AS Datum 
   FROM leads 
  WHERE created_at >= '2015-01-01' AND created_at <= '2018-01-01' 
    AND shopID = 4184 
GROUP BY Datum 
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(Datum, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'))`

I would appreciate any kind of help! And no, I cannot change the `Select` values or turn off the `full_group_mode`.

Comment: What error messages are you seeing when you have made the attempts?

Comment: There aren't error messages. It just isn't ordered by month and year... I guess because it's wrong "connected"... But created_ad contains valid dates! (timestamps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will sort by year and then month in ascending order:

```
order by substring(datum,4,4), substring(datum,1,2)
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16fab4/3

Comment: See the sqlfiddle.  Break datsum (mm.yyyy) into 2 parts: yyyy and mm using the substring function,

Comment: Yeah, but why isn't it `substring(datum, 4, 7), substring(datum, 1, 2)`? You break down the year just to the first char of the year. 2017 would be 2

Comment: Syntax of substring function: SUBSTRING(string, start, length). Check out this url: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp

Comment: I already did. But let's do an example. `datum` is `02.2017`. So char 1 would be `0`, char  1 would be `2`, char 3 would be `,` char 4 would be `2`. And if you say `substring(datum,4,4)` you get just the `2` of the year. Am I wrong?

Comment: The second 4 in substring(datum,4,4) is referring to the length of the substring.  Starting at the 4th character of datum for 4 characters: 2017

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y'), date_format(created_at, '%M') desc

This will sort the results by year ascending then by month descending.

Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ffc84/3/0) to see the query using MySql 5.6

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not working because of `sql_full_group_by_mode`. I didn't have selected `created_at` in `Select`. And if I replace `created_at` with `Datum` it isn't throwing any error message, but it isn't sorted...

Comment: ... in your Fiddle, year and month maybe reversed though.